# Turn off selected spring boot system metrics

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Currently spring boot actuator metrics returns metrics for various system parameters. I want to turn on some selected metrics parameters, for example; show only metrics related to memory and processor. I had several attempts to figure out solution but nothing worked for me. I see `SystemPublicMetrics` registers all basic system metrics and management system matrics, how can I turn on only few of them?

Required output:

```
{
  "mem": 495055,
  "mem.free": 372397,
  "processors": 4
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by disabling CacheMetricsAutoConfiguration of spring boot auto configuration at start-up by adding metrics class to exclusion list.

For instance to disable cache metrics add following at startup:

import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.cache.CacheMetricsAutoConfiguration;

@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {CacheMetricsAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
...
...

This should help..

Comment: Thanks :) this helped!

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to disable specific metrics. Rather, you will be able to enable/disable at endpoints only.

Following are the flags that you can add in application.properties to enable/disable specific endpoints in Spring Boot Actuator

```
endpoints.autoconfig.enabled=false
endpoints.beans.enabled=false
endpoints.configprops.enabled=false
endpoints.dump.enabled=false
endpoints.env.enabled=false
endpoints.health.enabled=true
endpoints.info.enabled=true
endpoints.metrics.enabled=false
endpoints.mappings.enabled=false
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=false
endpoints.trace.enabled=false
```